# Mapping tutorials can teach us something more about GIS

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I propose that there should be a tutorial module for GIS Stack Exchange, similar to [Cgtuts+](http://cg.tutsplus.com), which offers tutorials for beginner, intermediate and advanced computer graphics artists. Asking questions and getting answers is good but may not be the most efficient learning style for everyone.

To encourage people to write tutorials, we can award them with bounties, and we can make some premium tutorials which can only be viewed by giving bounties which will make people more interested than before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with most feature requests it is out of place on this site. Tutorials are not specific to GIS, and I bet if you searched around on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) you'd find this question asked and answered before.

Examples:

- [Tutorial section for Stack Overflow [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33048/tutorial-section-for-stack-overflow)
- [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)

What you can do is ask and answer a question yourself -- if the community feels it is a valuable contribution it will get upvoted, gaining you reputation, just like bounties. Anyone can reward you with a bounty if they think you have a really good question or answer.

I've done this a few times myself where I started out with a problem, started writing a question, did some additonal research and after coming upon a solution, posted an answer describing how I was able to solve the problem.

Lastly it's worth mentioning the [GIS Stack Exchange Blog](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1), which while it doesn't earn you reputation, is a great way to post tutorials (and really needs more contributors from a look at the last posting date).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be out of scope for Stack Exchange.

I think the quality of the answers should just be improved. Good answers should also explain why something is the case (and not purely state the facts). That way the questioner gains insight into the field and (hopefully) a few pointers on where to direct his next search.